# calling a new class on filter tag apache camel

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have this code on my router class

```
from("seda:singleInvoicesChannel")
                .filter(new LowEnoughAmountPredicate())
                .to("seda:filteredInvoicesChannel");
```

now iam trying to transfer it on my camel-context.xml with this

```
<route id="singleInvoicesChannel">
          <from uri="seda:singleInvoicesChannel"/>
          <filter>

          </filter>
          <to uri="seda:filteredInvoicesChannel"/>
      </route>
```

my question is what will i put inside the filter tag to fulfill the .filter(new LowEnoughAmountPredicate());.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Camel Message Filter Bean in Spring XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762743/how-to-use-camel-message-filter-bean-in-spring-xml)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fan of this Springish DSL but I just guess it could be something like this:

```
<bean id="filterBean" class="LowEnoughAmountPredicate"/>

  <route id="singleInvoicesChannel">
      <from uri="seda:singleInvoicesChannel"/>
      <filter>
         <custom ref="filterBean" />
      </filter>
      <to uri="seda:filteredInvoicesChannel"/>
  </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

The working Spring solution looks like that:

```
  <bean id="myPredicate" class="LowEnoughAmountPredicate"/>

  <route id="singleInvoicesChannel">
      <from uri="seda:singleInvoicesChannel"/>
      <filter>
         <method ref="myPredicate"/>
         <to uri="seda:filteredInvoicesChannel"/>
      </filter>
  </route>
```